# How to dynamically listen for an event in firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to listen for the changes on a node as follows.

`organizations/{org_slug}/projects/{pro_slug}/calculations/{calc_slug}`

I am able to do this in the firebase cloud function, is it possible to implement the same method in the node js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client SDKs don't have the ability to use a wildcard on any path component.  If you need to listen to changes to a document, you must be able to build an exact path to it.

Comment: Is it better to switch to the firebase realtime database or switch to cloud function?

Comment: If you're looking for an opinion, please post your question to a discussion forum such as Reddit.  Stack Overflow is only for programming questions, no product advice.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase